# Color-function does not get fired in c3chart directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, c3.js

I am passing dynamic data to the color function in c3chart directive as below

```
<chart-color color-function="getColors(id)"/>
```

and trying to change the default color used by the donut chart in c3 angular chart. The `getColors(id)` function is defined in the controller as shown below:

```
$scope.getColors = function(d){
  console.log(d);

  var c20b = d3.scale.category20();
  return c20b(d.id);
};
```

But the function does not get called while loading the chart. Is there any other way to apply custom colors to the charts other than this? I am new to c3 angular so any help here will be appreciated.

Comment: In `getColors`, you use `c20b(d.id);` but you call it with `getColors(id)`. Should it instead be `getColors(your_data_that_has_an_id_field)`? (Basically, are you accidentally doing like `id.id` in `$scope.getColors`?)

Comment: you are right I changed that but still function did not fire. After changing the directive to chart-colors the function was fired. But still the colors of the donut are not changed . The donut is taking only one color.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but you have a spelling mistake in your code:

```
<chart-color color-function="getColors"/>
```

should be

```
<chart-colors color-function="getColors"/>
```

And your function should be:

```
$scope.getColors = function(color, d){
  console.log(d);

  var c20b = d3.scale.category20();
  return c20b(d.id);
};
```